# How to use mockery on private classes?

Tags: php, unit-testing, reflection, phpunit, mockery

I want to write an unit test for a method which is using private method `getRandNumber()`.
In my test `getRandNumber()` should always return `1`.

How can I mock this method?

I've tried

```
$myModel = $this->createPartialMock(MyModel::class, ['getRandNumber']);

$reflector = new \ReflectionClass(MyModel::class);
$m = $reflector->getMethod('getRandNumber');
$m->setAccessible(true);

$myModel->method('getRandNumber')->willReturn(1);
```

getting error

```
  [PHPUnit\Framework\Warning] Trying to configure method "getRandNumber" which cannot be configured because it does not exist, has not been specified, is final, or is static
```

Comment: The [short official answer is no](https://github.com/mockery/mockery/issues/964).